# Get rotation and scale of picture after georeferencing using QGIS

Tags: qgis, geotiff-tiff, scale, rotate

How can I access the rotation and scaling information, that is visible during the georeferencing process in QGIS (see yellow marked text in the picture), after the georeferencing is completed and the TIF file is created?

I tried looking at the Metadata, but there is no info about this.

[image]